# ggplot to ggplotly doesn't work with customized geom_boxplot width

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, boxplot, ggplotly

When I try to set a customized width for my boxplot in ggplot, it works fine:

```
p=ggplot(iris, aes(x = Species,y=Sepal.Length )) + geom_boxplot(width=0.1)
```

But when I try to use ggplotly, the width (and the hjust) is default:

```
p %>% ggplotly()
```

What am I doing wrong or is this a bug in ggplotly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use layout to set the boxgap:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)

p <- ggplot(iris, aes(x = Species,y=Sepal.Length )) +
   geom_boxplot()

ggplotly(p) %>% plotly::layout(boxgap=0.9)
```

See also https://plot.ly/python/box-plots/#Grouped-Box-Plot